# django ifequal casting issue

Tags: django

i have in my template:

```
    <select name="meetingTimeDay">
    {% for k in days2 %}
      <option value="{{ forloop.counter0 }}"{% ifequal c.meetingTime|date:"w", forloop.counter0 %}selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ k }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

where days2 is:

```
days2 = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

but the ifequal doesn't work. i render out both forloop.counter0 and meetingTime|date:"w" and 1 day WILL match visually. I think it may be a casting problem.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the comma separating the values

```
{% ifequal c.meetingTime|date:'w' forloop.counter0 %}
```

Also the if tag has come a long way

```
{% if c.meetingTime|date:'w' == forloop.counter0 %}
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: sorry but both of them suggetions result in:

    TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted

Comment: The first suggestion should read 'ifequal', not 'if equal'. The 2nd suggestion will only work with Django 1.2 (or later).

Comment: @all ok thanks for everyones help. first, no variation of the above evaluation worked. second, i extracted the weekday() in python and sent it through as a separate variable to Django, and it works. Messy but it works.